# User-exclusive command in discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot in Python and I want to create a command that only I can use. Here's an example piece of code I tried, but didn't work:

```
    #replace MY_USER_ID with user ID number.
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        if message.author == "<@MY_USER_ID>":
            await message.channel.send('Hello creator!')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Using Python 3.8.5 and discord.py 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the author's id using `message.author.id` and pass your id as an `int` not a `str`.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        if message.author.id == 1234567890:
            await message.channel.send('Hello creator!')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```